# How can I read words (instead of lines) from a file?

Tags: bash

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974977/read-characters-from-a-text-file-using-bash) about how to read n characters from a text file using bash. I would like to know how to read a word at a time from a file that looks like:

```
example text
example1 text1
example2 text2
example3 text3
```

Can anyone explain that to me, or show me an easy example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `read` command by default reads whole lines. So the solution is probably to read the whole line and then split it on whitespace with e.g. `for`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        echo "word = '$word'"
    done
done <"myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Where should I can the name of my file in the above code?

Comment: @Admia Remember that `read` reads from standard input. The "best" way (IMO) to solve it is to put the code in a function. And since functions can be called just like any other command, it can also be used with redirection. So then you can do e.g. `function_with_read_loop < some_file`.

Comment: If your line contains `*` as a standalone element, you'll get a list of filenames in the current directory from `for word in $line`. (Also, `read` without `-r` will munge backslash literals).

Answer (score 24):

The way to do this with standard input is by passing the `-a` flag to read:

```
read -a words
echo "${words[@]}"
```

This will read your entire line into an indexed array variable, in this case named *words*. You can then perform any array operations you like on *words* with [shell parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

For file-oriented operations, current versions of Bash also support the mapfile [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). For example:

```
mapfile < /etc/passwd
echo ${MAPFILE[0]}
```

Either way, arrays are the way to go. It's worth your time to familiarize yourself with [Bash array syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) to make the most of this feature.

Comment: This question is tagged bash, but for future readers, note these are both bash-specific and will not work in the posix shell.

Answer (score 15):

Ordinarily, you should read from a file using a `while read -r line` loop. To do this and parse the words on the lines requires nesting a `for` loop inside the `while` loop.

Here is a technique that works without requiring nested loops:

```
for word in $(<inputfile)
do
    echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that string-splitting is "ordinarily" correct. If you have a `*` in your file, you'll get a list of names in the current directory in your output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That issue also affects the accepted answer (the technique described in my second sentence). The technique in my code snippet fails in the same way.

Answer (score 10):

In the context given, where the number of words is known:

```
while read -r word1 word2 _; do
  echo "Read a line with word1 of $word1 and word2 of $word2"
done
```

If you want to read each line into an array, `read -a` will put the first word into element 0 of your array, the second into element 1, etc:

```
while read -r -a words; do
  echo "First word is ${words[0]}; second word is ${words[1]}"
  declare -p words # print the whole array
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, just use space as delimiter (`read -d ' '`). This method requires some preprocessing to translate newlines into spaces (using `tr`) and to merge several spaces into a single one (using `sed`):

```
{
 tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/  */ /g' | while read -d ' ' WORD
 do
  echo -n "<${WORD}> "
 done
 echo
} << EOF
Here you have some words, including * wildcards
that don't get expanded,
multiple   spaces   between   words,
    and lines with spaces at the begining.
EOF
```

The main advantage of this method is that you don't need to worry about the array syntax and just work as with a `for` loop, but without wildcard expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question and the proposed answers, but I don't see listed this simple possibile solution:

```
for word in `cat inputfile`
do
  echo $word
done
```

Comment: This isn't listed for a good reason: It's extremely buggy. If your input file has a `*` in it, you'll get a list of files in the current directory in your output -- and because the argument to `echo` isn't quoted, if one of your filenames splits into a set of words that contains a glob, that glob will *also* be expanded. See also [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using AWK too:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' text_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `xargs` which reads word delimited by space *or* newline and `echo` to print one per line:

```
<some-file xargs -n1 echo

some-command | xargs -n1 echo
```

That also works well for large or slow streams of data because it does not need to read the whole input at once.

I’ve used this to read 1 table name at a time from SQLite which prints table names in a column layout:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite .tables | xargs -n1 echo | while read table; do echo "1 table: $table"; done
```