# Print every word and its number of occurrences, using pure `bash`

Tags: bash, shell

I have below given code.  I want to print each word and its number of occurrences without using external utils such as `wc`, `awk`, `tr`, *etc.*

I am able to count the total number of words, but here I have also one issue:  in the output I am not getting total word count, the output is less than what it should be.

What should I do?

```
#!/bin/bash
#v=1

echo -n "ENTER FILE NAME: "
read file
IFS=$'\n'
cnew_line=`echo -e "\n"`
cspace=`echo  " "`

if [ $# -ne 0 ] 
then

echo "You didn't entered a filename as a parameter"
exit

elif [ $# -eq 0 ] 
then
filename="$file"

num_line=0
num_word=0
num_char=0

while read -n1  w
do
if [ "$w" = "$cnew_line" ]
then
(( num_line++ ))
elif [ "$w" = "$cspace" ]
then

(( num_word++ ))

else
(( num_char++ ))
fi
done < "$filename"


echo "Line Number = $num_line"
echo "Word Number = $num_word"
echo "Character Number =$num_char"

fi

    enter code here
```

Comment: Doing this in pure Bash is an extremely inefficient and clunky use of tools. Can you explain why you want to do this in an environment which isn't a particularly good fit for the task? Also, your code lacks indentation and triggers a number of warnings on http://shellcheck.net/. You should get these things into shape before asking for help here.

Comment: Assinging a newline to `IFS` with `IFS=$'\n'` and then doing it again the wrong way on the next line suggests you don't really understand your own code.  Hint: `cnew_line` does not end up containing a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an associative array for counting the words, a bit like this:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

declare -A words

while read line
do
    for word in $line
    do
        ((words[$word]++))
    done
done

for i in "${!words[@]}"
do
    echo "$i:" "${words[$i]}"
done
```

Testing it:

```
$ echo this is a test is this | bash foo.sh
is: 2
this: 2
a: 1
test: 1
```

This answer was constructed pretty much from these fine answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932020/4162356) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3113285/4162356). Don't forget to upvote them.

Comment: That code considers punctuation part of a word, and it can't handle apostrophes.  Example:  `echo "Seward's folly" | bash foo.sh` returns "*bad array subscript*".

Answer (score 0):

Two improved versions of [James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47881196/6136214), (which considers punctuation part of a word, and breaks on groups of double and single quotes):

1. Punctuation considered part of word:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   declare -A words

   while read line ; do
       for word in ${line} ; do
           ((words[${word@Q}]++))
   done ; done

   for i in ${!words[@]} ; do
       echo ${i}: ${words[$i]}
   done
   ```
2. Punctuation *not* part of word, (like `wc`):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   declare -A words

   while read line ; do
       line="${line//[[:punct:]]}"
       for word in ${line} ;do 
           ((words[${word}]++))
   done ; done

   for i in ${!words[@]} ;do
       echo ${i}: ${words[$i]}
   done
   ```

Tested code, with tricky quoted text:

- `fortune -m "swear" | bash foo.sh`
- `man bash | ./foo.sh  | sort -gr -k2 | head`